# R: subset - Error: number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Tags: r

I'm new to R and don't know how to fix this error message:

> Error in dbeta[is.finite(design$prob), ] <- dbeta.subset :    number
> of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

I got this error message when I tried to carry out svycoxph with the subset I created with the following code:

```
design_lp <- svydesign(id= ~point,
      data = lp1, 
      weights=~w1)    
design_sub <- subset(design_lp, vital==1)
```

I wanted to create a subset with only patients that died (=> vital ==1) so I can carry out analyses of this subset. But as mentioned I get this error message and I do not know how to fix it.

Does someone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Please, do always include a reproducible example. We don't even know what package `svydesign` belongs to and, more importan, what class of objects it returns (which is what you are using as input of `subset`).

Comment: I believe that you have to use `select` to tell `subset` exactly which columns you are keeping from the original data. But without a reproducible example it's impossible for me to say for sure this is the problem.